# Slider not working, No errors on Console - Javascript Vanilla

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a slider with Javascript, However i cannot seem to get it to work, It is not showing any errors in the console as to why it doesn't seem to work.

It appears the `overflow:hidden` in the css, seems to hide everything, instead of what overflows...

From what i can see, is that it is not grabbing the `li` images, although i do not know why, unless the var `li` Items assignment does not work.

Here is the code:

```js
function Slide (){
 ul = document.getElementById("slide");
 liItems = ul.children;
 imageNumber = liItems.length;
 imageWidth = liItems[0].children[0].offsetwidth;
 // Set UL's Width as total width of all images in slider.
 ul.style.width = parseInt(imageWidth * imageNumber) + "px";
 // Left + Right Arrows
 leftArrow = document.getElementById("left");
 rightArrow = document.getElementById("right");

  function slider(ul){
   animate({
    delay: 17,
    duration: 4000,
    delta:function(p){
     return Math.max(0, -1 + 2 * p)},
    step:function(delta){
     ul.style.left = "-"+ parseInt(currentImage * imageWidth + delta * imageWidth) + "px";
     },
    callback:function(){
     currentImage++;
     //Keep sliding if not last image
     if (currentImage < imageNumber -1){
      slider(ul);
     }
     // Slide back to first image, if last image
     else {
      leftPosition = (imageNumber -1) * imageWidth;
      //after set seconds, call goback for first image
      setTimeout(function(){goBack(leftPosition)},3000);
      setTimeout(function(){slider(ul)},5000);
     }
    }
   });
  
   function goBack (leftPosition){
     currentImage = 0;
     id = setInterval(function(){
      if (leftPosition >= 0){
       ul.style.left = '-' + parseInt(leftPosition) + "px";
       leftPosition -= imageWidth/10;
      }else {
       clearInterval(id);
      }
     }, 17);
    }
   function animate(opts){
    start = new Date;
    id = setInterval (function(){
     timePassed = new Date - start;
     progress = timePassed / opts.duration
      if (progress > 1){
       progress = 1;
      }
     delta = opts.delta(progress);
     opts.step(delta);
      if (progress == 1){
       clearInterval(id);
       opts.callback();
      }
    }, opts.delay || 17);
   }
  }
 }
window.onload = Slide;
```

```css
    #sliderwrap {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}
#left {
 width: 10%;
 height: 75px;
 top: 50%;
 left: 20px;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 font-size: 4vmax;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
}
#left p, #right p {
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 75px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 color: #ff69b4;
}
#right {
 width: 10%;
 height: 75px;
 top: 50%;
 right: 20px;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); 
 font-size: 4vmax;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
}
#slide {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 0;
}
#slide li {
 max-width: 100%;
 list-style-type: none;
}
#slide img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div id="sliderwrap">
  <div id="left">
   <p> < </p>
  </div>
  <ul id="slide">
   <li><img src="http://www.wallpapercase.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/My-Style-Photo-Wallpaper-810x506.jpg" alt="1" id="one"/></li>
   <li><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/c5/91/b2/c591b2dab7ef73898e65c4660d63696f.jpg" alt="2" id="two"/></li>
   <li><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/79/65/a2/7965a2e1141be21bdfc17d381360505a.jpg" alt="3" id="three"/></li>
   <li><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/63/01/9d/63019d238358413828cb533dc5277971.jpg" alt="4" id="four"/></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="right">
   <p> > </p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to never call the function `slider()` which looks like it should initialize the slider. Try to add something like `slider(document.getElementById('slider'))` at the end of your `Slide()` function

Comment: Could you elaborate, I have nested the Slider() function inside the Slide() function, which is called onload at the end of the script?

Comment: sure - the function is defined, but never called. function slider(ul){
   animate({ ... only defines it.

Comment: Thanks, Now im getting another error to troubleshoot in the Slider() :)